# How to use priority_queue with a non-static compare method of class instance?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, priority-queue, custom-compare

Suppose I have a simple class like this:

```
class Test {
public:
  Test(int reference) { m_reference = reference; }
  void feed(int x) { m_data.push_back(x); }
  int get() { return m_data.front(); }
private:
  int m_reference;
  std::vector<int> m_data;
};
```

Instead of a [`std::vector`](https://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), I would like to feed values into a [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue). Instead of returning the `.front()` value, I would like to `.get()` the `.top()` value of the `priority_queue` based on a custom compare function. Let's say this custom comparison is computed as the absolute difference between a value and the instance `reference`.

I have **no idea** how to declare the `std::priority_queue` in my class attributes.

I have tried:

```
bool compare(int a, int b) {
    return std::abs(a - m_reference) < std::abs(b - m_reference);
}
```

And then:

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(&Test::compare)> m_priority;
```

I also tried with `std::function` like this but this raises multiple errors:

```
std::function<bool(int a, int b)>> pq([this](int a, int b){
   return std::abs(a - m_reference) < std::abs(b - m_reference);
});
```

But this won't work (see [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/PreciousTimelyPorts)).

Any idea how to solve this please?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher If I add `static`, will this still work despite the `reference` attribute being non-static?

Comment: What about using a lambda and capturing the instance you want to use for the comparison?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I tried but was unable to capture `[this]` (as I need it for the `m_reference` attribute). But I haven't much experience with lambda functions, maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: @Delgan Can you show what you tried with the lambda in your question please? Maybe we could fix your problem then. Generally it should be possible to capture `this.`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ there is a problem of that `priority_queue` declaration using lambda

Comment: @Slava It looks like the OP writing the answer, did solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to make it work by using:

```
std::function<bool(int,int)> comp = [this](int a, int b) { return std::abs(a - m_reference) < std::abs(b - m_reference); };
```

with

```
Test(int reference) : m_priority(comp) { m_reference = reference; }
```

and

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(comp)> m_priority;
```

You also need to `#include <functional>`

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you wanted?

You can also make your comparator a `struct` or something and use it instead of `std::function` if you don't want any performance drawbacks.

Update:

Version with struct would look like this (you can pass a `this` pointer instead of reference to `int` or however you prefer it):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <cmath>

class Test {
public:
    Test(int reference) : m_priority(comp(m_reference)) { m_reference = reference; }
    void feed(int x) { m_data.push_back(x); }
    int get() { return m_priority.top(); }

    struct comp {
        int& reference;
        comp(int& ref) : reference(ref) {}
        bool operator()(int a, int b) { return std::abs(a - reference) < std::abs(b - reference); };
    };

private:
    int m_reference;
    std::vector<int> m_data;
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, comp> m_priority;
};
```

Comment: Ok, it seems the solution using `struct` is probably the best one. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

If you are fine using `std::function` (it may have slight overhead) it would work but you tried to submit lambda into type declaration:

```
std::priority_queue<
        int,
        std::vector<int>,
        std::function<bool(int,int)> comp = [this](int a, int b) { return std::abs(a - m_reference) < std::abs(b - m_reference); }> m_priority;
```

this would not work. You need to use `std::function` as a type:

```
std::priority_queue<
        int,
        std::vector<int>,
        std::function<bool(int,int)>> m_priority;
```

and then submit lambda into `m_priority` ctor as parameter:

```
Test(int reference) :
    m_reference( reference ),
    m_priority( [ref=reference]( int a, int b ) {
        return std::abs( a - ref ) < std::abs( b - ref ); 
    } )
 {
 }
```

then it would work. [Live example](https://ideone.com/XuSzwL)

Answer (score 2):

If you are ever going to change the `m_reference` value, you would need to re-sort the `std::priority_queue`. The below is a (probably) clumsy way of doing it, which will be very costly if done often and/or the queue is big, but it gets the job done. The code is meant to be an add-on to @Slavas answer.

```
public:
    void set_reference(int x) {
        m_reference = x;
        sort();
    }
private:
    void sort() {
        std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::function<bool(int,int)>> tmp(
            [this](int a, int b) { return std::abs(a - m_reference) < std::abs(b - m_reference); }
        );
        while(m_priority.size()) {
            tmp.emplace(std::move(m_priority.top()));
            m_priority.pop();
        }
        std::swap(tmp, m_priority);
    }
```